# Man pages for gcc Library functions

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, ubuntu

I want to view function man pages in gcc on Ubuntu.

For instance, say I want to look up a certain function accept(), I can issue a command `man acccept`, which gives me the function definition.

However, for other C library functions like mknod() issuing commands like `man mknod` results in the man page of the UNIX command mknod (rather than the C function mknod) showing up. Is there any way to view the man page of C functions like mknod() whose names coincides with UNIX commands?

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that `accept`, for example, is not a gcc function.  Most library functions are either system calls (provided by the operating system) or are part of the C library.  gcc generally uses whatever C library is available on the system (though a few are provided along with gcc itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mknod()` the C function lives in section 2 of the man pages. You can view it using:

```
man -s2 mknod
```

In general things like this are likely to live in either section 2 (system calls) or section 3 (library calls)

Comment: @AdrianCornish - skipping the `-s` is a GNU extension. `man 2 mknod` on Solaris for example does not give mknod(2).

Comment: @awoodland - Good to know - been a while since I worked with Solaris - pretty sure it works on AIX though.

Answer (score 4):

According to `man man`, you can optionally give the section of the manual before the page. Section 1 is user commands, 2 system calls and 3 library functions, so:

```
man 1 printf
man 3 printf
```

give the shell command and the C library function printf, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to search and list all man pages you can give `man -k <your-keyword>`, in your case it would be like `man -k mknod`. This will return names and section of all the man pages available and resembles to given keyword.

It will also be useful when you can't recollect exact function name.